# How to make a Java program to constantly check if there has been changes and loop it until there is

Tags: java, loops

I'm trying to figure out how to make my java program (code is below) to check after every 5 seconds if the color of the background has changed and then if it has changed then using `java.awt.robot` go to a certain area of screen and click.

```
    Color queueColor1 = robot.getPixelColor(614, 756);
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
    Color queueColor2 = robot.getPixelColor(614, 756);
    System.out.println(queueColor1);
    System.out.println(queueColor2);
    boolean readyCheck = (queueColor1 != queueColor2);
    if (readyCheck = false) {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);

    } while (queueColor1 != queueColor2);
        robot.mouseMove(720, 629);
        robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
}
```

I already had made a code where it does the same thing but it wasn't a loop. I had to copy the lines over and over again, till with `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);` it was total of 2 minutes and I was replacing every "queueColor2" with "queueColor3.....16" or something. So it was comparing "queueColor1" with "queueColor3" and so on.

Comment: What's your question? Is there a problem with your code?

Comment: Yes, there is. It doesn't work as intended. When the color changes it does nothing. If I try to write "do -> while" thingy for some reason it doesn't recognize the boolean "readyCheck" anymore like it hasnt been implemented in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a number of problems:
- The statement `(queueColor1 != queueColor2)` always returns `true` since you're comparing the objects and not their contents.
- `if (readyCheck = false)` assigns `false` to the variable
- your loop `while (queueColor1 != queueColor2);` is infinite (see above)

You might try something like this (it's just a hint; I didn't even check whether it compiles)

```
Color old_color = robot.getPixelColor(614, 756);
for (;;)
{
  TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
  Color new_color = robot.getPixelColor(614, 756);
  if (!new_color.equals(old_color))
  {
    robot.mouseMove(720, 629);
    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);    
    old_color = new_color;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this seem to be working. I'll tweak it a little bit but seems to be it :)